# Disable Auto Merge in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

We are using VSTS with Git as the repo. We are having many issues with Auto Merge when branches are merged. Is there a way to turn off auto merge in VSTS? I cant find any settings for the same in VS. gitattribute file approach also has not worked. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For now, VSTS does not have such settings to disable the option of auto-complete for all pull request which specified with branch policies.

The workaround for now is **cancel auto-complete** manually on the pull requests which you set auto-complete.

[image]

Besides, you can also suggest this feature by creating an [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/?query=enable%20to%20disable%20the%20option%20auto-complete%20pull%20request).